# I am not able to set layout for my other activity

Tags: android, kotlin

I have implemented the layout but when I am running the app, blank screen is coming. I've attached the manifest file as well as the code which is being used for setting the layout. I am using intent to start this activity from `MainActivity`.

Android Manifest file

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.example.safetyapp">
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_PHONE_NUMBERS"></uses-permission>

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round"
        android:supportsRtl="true"
        android:theme="@style/Theme.SafetyApp">
        <activity android:name=".Defence_tips">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name = "android.intent.action.MAIN"/>

            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
        <activity android:name=".Details">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name = "android.intent.action.MAIN"/>
           
        </intent-filter>
        </activity>

        <activity android:name=".MainActivity">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
    </application>

</manifest>
```

Layout file

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="@color/teal_700"
    tools:context=".Details">

</LinearLayout>
```

File from where I am setting the layout

```
package com.example.safetyapp

import android.os.Bundle
import android.os.PersistableBundle
import android.widget.Button
import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity

class Details: AppCompatActivity(){

    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?, persistentState: PersistableBundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState, persistentState)
        setContentView(R.layout.details)
    }

}
```

Comment: But the layout consists nothing, then why or how do you expect a non-blank layout?

Comment: @LalitFauzdar It has a background colour. It had 2 editText's but I removed it for posting this question so that the code doesn't look lengthy.

Comment: You've not set the orientation of the `LinearLayout`, try setting one and share the complete layout, code doesn't have any problem, must be with the layout.

Comment: add code in your linear layout and re-run the app

Answer (score 0):

In your Manifest file, you have 3 intent filters, all listed as main. Only put the intent filter for the activity you want to show when your user first starts the app (Details?, I think), and remove the rest.

The code you should put under activity you want to start first.

```
<intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
```